# Getting "Missing Data Provider or Data Packet" error - Exhange data as stream within clientdataset

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, datasnap

I am using datasnap technology where I got a client a server application.
The Server gets the data from database and puts into stream which is then fetched at client side.
I keep getting a "Missing Data Provider or Data Packet" error on the client side code.

**Server side code:**

```
function GetFiles(ClientID: integer): TStream;
var
  CDS: TClientDataSet;
begin
  try
  Result := TMemoryStream.Create;
  CDS := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
  with adsFiles do   // ads is adodataset and dspFiles is the dataset provider which has its dataset property set to adsFiles
  begin
    Close;
    Parameters.ParamByName('ClientID').Value := ClientID;
    Open;
    CDS.Data :=  dspFiles.Data;
    CDS.Open; 
    CDS.SaveToStream(Result);
    Result.Position := 0;
  end;
  finally
    CDS.Free;
  end;
```

**Client Side Code:**

```
procedure ExportData;
var
   StreamData: TStream;
begin
    StreamData := SvrMethodClass.GetFiles(AClientID);
    StreamData.Seek(0,soFromBeginning);
    StreamData.Position:= 0;
    cdsClientFiles.LoadFromStream(StreamData); // getting the error message "Missing Data Provider or Data Packet" 
    cdsClientFiles.Open;
end;
```

Client side I have dropped a clientdataset component and trying to load the data into this dataset where the issue is raised any help pointing me where I am going wrong would be really appreciated. Thanks

similar question: [Streaming TClientDataSet using Datasnap in Delphi XE6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37450199/streaming-tclientdataset-using-datasnap-in-delphi-xe6)
checked the solution but it did not work out

Comment: Read the comments on the q you linked, then do some debugging,  Readers who cannot reproduce your problem are unlikely to be able to help you, so provide an MCVE.  Meanwhile, -1.

Comment: Btw, you are not checking whether `ads` returns any rows.  Is that intentional?

Comment: @MartynA I checked server side I can see it returns rows and I even tried to save the data to xml and it is 204MB.

Comment: The problem here, at least from my experience, is where you do this `CDS.Data :=  dspFiles.Data;`. I can't imagine why you would do this, since it's completely unnecessary.

Comment: Btw, there seems to be a long-standing problem retrieving streams over Datasnap.  See, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41854631/cant-retrieve-tstreams-bigger-than-around-260-000-bytes-from-a-datasnap-server

Comment: @MartynA Thanks for pointing this out.
after adding the following lines at client side before cdsClientFiles.LoadFromStream(StreamData)  I was able to get the issue resolved  
cdsClientFiles.CreateDataSet;
cdsClientFiles.Close;

But not able to get the data as its bigger in size..

Comment: @MartynA I modified the query to fetch only one row from database and I can see it client side but when it goes above 1 row(which had pdf as blob) client side I cannot see data . this clearly tells that stream in datsnap model not able to get large data. 
Any idea ho I can get this done? I am at a crucial point where lot of time is invested .. any direction really appreciated.

Comment: Well, my experiments at the time I commented on the other q (or maybe another similar one) showed that there is no similar problem when the data returned from the server is a string rather than a stream.  So I suggested that the user returned the "blob" as a Base64-encoded string.

Comment: @MartynA Ys you are right. In that example it has got Firedac component which allows creating blob of the entire dataset data. In ADO client dataset I have been looking for the same could not find it. It has CreateBlobStream which takes only a single column. In my case I want to get other columns as well in short entire dataset.

Comment: In that case, you could probably avoid using Base64 - see update to my answer.

Comment: @MartynA Ok will check and let you know. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a lot of time investigating the problems with returning data as a stream from a datasnap server - see e.g. [Can't retrieve TStreams bigger than around 260.000 bytes from a Datasnap Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41854631/cant-retrieve-tstreams-bigger-than-around-260-000-bytes-from-a-datasnap-server), but was unable to come up with a satisfactory solution for stream data.

However, experiments revealed that a similar problem does not occur with string data (I tested strings up to several hundred megabytes).  So, I would suggest you try sending your binary/blob data from the Datasnap server as a Base64-encoded string.

Of course, if a string representation of your ADO or CDS data is adequate for what you want, one way to achieve that would be to do an `adsFile.SaveToFile(..., pfXML)` or `CDS.SaveToFile(... dfXML)` in the server method, then return the resulting file as a string.

Comment: I accept this answer however this would give out of memory issue server side. I am able to get the task from server side on data set level where keep the reference of primary key in one data set and later at each iteration export a single file with blob data from another data set. 
Thanks for the help:)